# How to append data in a div with the save data?

Tags: jquery

How to append data in a div ?I have div i show some data the from text file in that div .Now i want append some data  from from previous data .How to append data ?

```
<div id="realTimeContents" class="realtimeContend_h"></div>
```

I read data from save data like that.

```
reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
    $("#realTimeContents").text(evt.target.result);
};
```

Now i want to append data i am using like this but it is not appending ?

```
function nativePluginResultHandler(result) {
    $('#realTimeContents').html(result);
}
```

Comment: do you want it in the form of **<div>result</div>** ?

Comment: Don't you have in your `result` argument Array of Objects or Object? If it's so, you have to draw it manually, but we need to know, what you have in `result` argument

Comment: have you looked at **.text()** : http://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score 2):

use `.append()`

```
$('#realTimeContents').append(result);
```

http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$('#realTimeContents').html($('#realTimeContents').html() + result);
```

Comment: or just use `.append()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your result to text

```
$('#realTimeContents').html($('#realTimeContents').html() + result.text() );
```

http://api.jquery.com/text/